# Search a log file for total count of unique ips

Tags: unix, awk, ip, unique, tail

I'm using this following format to get the counts of how many times unique IPs hit my website.

Search a log file for total count of unique ips

```
zcat *file* | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

This gives me a list of IPs and it's occurrence.

```
1001 109.165.113.xxx
1001 178.137.88.xxx
1001 178.175.13.xxx
1001 81.4.217.xxx
1060 74.122.180.xxx
1103 67.201.52.xxx
1203 81.144.138.xxx
1670 54.240.158.xxx
1697 54.239.137.xxx
2789 39.183.147.xxx
4630 93.158.143.xxx
```

What I want to find out is simple and if it can be done on a single command line.

I just want the count of this list.  So from the above example.  I want for the buffer to tell me 11.  I thought I could use a second AWK command to count the unique occurrence of the 2nd output but I guess you cannot use AWK twice in a single command line.

Obviously I can output the above to a log file and then run a second awk command to count the unique occurrence of the 2nd field(IPS) but I was hoping to get this done in a single command.

Comment: replace `sort|uniq -c|sort -n` with `sort -u | wc -l`

Comment: And you can use awk as many times as you like in a pipeline

Answer (score 2):

Here is the awk code to get total count of unique ips

```
zcat *file* | awk '{a[$1]} END {print length(a)}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want:

```
zcat ... |
awk '{cnt[$1]++} END{for (ip in cnt) {unq++; print cnt[ip], ip}; print unq+0}'
```

If you have GNU awk you can add `BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"}` at the front to get the loop output sorted, see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning.